# Is there a smart date API for Java which recognizes the pattern itself?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have the following input cases, but I don't want to examine the format myself and change the  pattern everytime. I currently make use of `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");`, this fails as soon as `a), c)` or `d)` are applied.

```
a) 1.1.12      => 01.01.0012 x
b) 01.01.2012  => 01.01.2012 ✓
c) 01.01.12    => 01.01.0012 x
d) 1.1.2012    => 01.00.2012 x
```

I can assure that the format is D.M.Y, but not if it's long or short or mixed up. Is there already a function in Joda which helps to choose the pattern given on a "base pattern"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a search path of patterns.  Some dates are ambiguous, so you need to know how you want to handle them e.g. is 1.2.3 the first of Feb 3 AD/1903/2003 or second of January, 3 AD or 1 AD/1901/2001 Feb the third.

A simple pattern I use (except I cache the SimpleDateFormat objects ;)

```
public static Date parseDate(String dateStr) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // optionally change the separator
    dateStr = dateStr.replaceAll("\\D+", "/");

    for (String fmt : "dd/MM/yy,yyyy/MM/dd,dd/MM/yyyy".split(",")) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt);
            sdf.setLenient(false);
            return sdf.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse date '" + dateStr + "'");
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    String dates = "1.2.12\n" +
            "01.02.2012\n" +
            "2012.02.01\n" +
            "01-01-12\n" +
            "1.1.2012";
    for (String dateStr : dates.split("\n")) {
        Object result;
        try {
            result = parseDate(dateStr);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            result = e;
        }
        System.out.println(dateStr + " => " + result);
    }
}
```

prints

```
1.2.12 => Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012
01.02.2012 => Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012
2012.02.01 => Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012
01-01-12 => Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012
1.1.2012 => Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012
```

Comment: I don't know about a better way, but I just want to warn that relying on exceptions as a part of a program flow is against best practices, as it's harming performance.

Comment: Thank you very much, the `#setLenient` is very helpful, didn't know that :) May I ask you a style question? Don't you like `Arrays.asList("dd/MM/yy", "yyyy/MM/dd", "dd/MM/yyyy")` or `new Object[] { .. }` or why are you using the `#split()` method? Isn't that more expensive?

Comment: I like split because its more concise. Its more expensive, but its simple to use a constant so its only performed once on startup.  Caching the SimpleDateFormat is more important as creating these is much more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got a better solution using Joda-Time. I got it down to two parsers that you have to try:

```
    DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendDayOfMonth(1)
            .appendLiteral('.')
            .appendMonthOfYear(1)
            .appendLiteral('.')
            .appendTwoDigitYear(1970) // Notice this!!
            .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(f.parseDateTime("01.1.12"));
    System.out.println(f.parseDateTime("01.01.12"));

    f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendDayOfMonth(1)
            .appendLiteral('.')
            .appendMonthOfYear(1)
            .appendLiteral('.')
            .appendYear(4,4)
            .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(f.parseDateTime("01.01.2012"));
    System.out.println(f.parseDateTime("1.1.2012"));
    System.out.println(f.parseDateTime("01.1.2012"));
```

Comment: If you think of using try-catch-blocks, I would say that's too expensive. One top of that in my opinion exceptions should only be used for really exceptional things.

Comment: Well, if it is too expensive then there is an easy solution. Validate the structure with a regex first and then parse it with the appropriate `DateTimeFormatter`. Also, my solution is just as expensive as the accepted solution but using Jodatime as requested, not the standard JDK `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: True. It wasn't my intention to criticise your solution. I thought I should annotate it for others reading this question. I think the solution to this problem depends on personal preference. In my oppinion your answer fits better to this exact question than the accepted one...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any reference to java.util.Data, you'll have to do it like this:

```
public DateTime getDateTime(String text) {
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder fb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
    fb.appendDayOfMonth(2);
    fb.appendLiteral('.');
    fb.appendMonthOfYear(2);
    fb.appendLiteral('.');
    fb.appendYear(2, 4);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = fb.toFormatter();

    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
    if (dt.getYear() < 2000) {
        dt = dt.plusYear(2000);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

But I would recommend this solution:

```
public DateTime getDateTime(String text) {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    java.util.Date jud = f.parse(text);
    if (jud != null) {
        return new DateTime(jud);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Both should do the trick and work for your examples.

Note: As Alberto said, you should validate your input first using regular expressions, because SimpleDateFormat doesn't have a very tight matching with this usage and because it's always a good idea to validate input.

Comment: I think one shouldn't start inventing the wheel twice ;) (If that's the right proverb in english...)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you are approaching the problem from the wrong perspective, if you have an input which consist on a list of Strings that represent dates, but in different formats, then you have a text validation problem, not a date formatting problem.

Again, this is only my opinion, but I think you'll find it easier if what you do is create a text parser that changes the text for all this inputs when necessary to a more suitable text format for your date parser, this way you can use more powerful utilities like regex...